# Encode & decode 2D cell array in matlab does not match original data format

Tags: .net, json, matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm using Matlab 2017b and having some trouble encoding ans decoding a two dimensional cell array; when I encode and decode I get a different output then the original.

```
data = 
  279x62 cell array

jsonencode(data) = 
  ['cell1','cell2','cell3' ... etc ]

jsondecode(ans) = 
  17298x1 cell array
```

I tried converting the matrix to string as well but got back a 279x1 call array of 62x1 cells. Is there any way I can format the data to ensure a 2D array is generated from the jsondecode matching the input to jsonencode?

Ultimately, I'd be passing the encoded json object to a .NET application but I'd need it to be decoded into a 2D array. I feel like there must be something simple I'm overlooking but I'm quite stuck, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) ought to do it. Note that `jsonencode` will flatten your input 2D cell array so that all of the columns are stacked into a single array.  Therefore, using `jsondecode` of this output will return a 1D cell array.  Therefore, restructure it back to a 2D matrix of `279 x 62`.  Assuming `data` is already created in your workspace:

```
% Encode the data
D = jsonencode(data);

% Decode it
out = reshape(jsondecode(D), size(data));
```

Note that I used [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)`(data)` instead of hardcoding the dimensions of the reshape so that it can adapt to whatever size your `data` cell array is prior to creating the JSON text.

Comment: Thanks that works for matlab, but does that mean there is no way to directly decode in .NET using Newtonsoft Json for example and get a 2D array? I think it would be possible to write a custom decode but was trying to keep as generic as I could.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with that framework. I answered using MATLAB only as I thought that was the main framework you're using.